# sum variables within R dataframe

Tags: r

I'm sorry, I'm sure a similar question has already been asked but I'm afraid I can't find it.  I merely want to sum a lot of variables within a dataframe.  As a small example, what I'd like to do is calculate df$e as below.

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=(c(6,7,8,9,10)), 
                 c=c(1,2,3,4,5), d=(c(6,7,8,9,10)))

df$e <- with(df, a+b+c+d) # this is the right answer
```

But I want to express it by saying df$e <- "the sum of all the variables between a and d."

Thank you!  Help also appreciated in tagging.

ANSWER: `df$e <- rowSums(subset(df, select=a:d))`

I didn't express that I needed it very clearly, but I was as ignorant of `subset` as I was of `rowSums`.

Comment: If you can work with a matrix/table, `addmargins` and `margin.table` can come handy.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for `rowSums()` ?

```
> df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=(c(6,7,8,9,10)), 
+                  c=c(1,2,3,4,5), d=(c(6,7,8,9,10)))
> with(df, a+b+c+d)
[1] 14 18 22 26 30
> rowSums(df)
[1] 14 18 22 26 30
>
```

which you can of course also assign back into `df`:

```
> df$e <- rowSums(df)
> df
  a  b c  d  e
1 1  6 1  6 14
2 2  7 2  7 18
3 3  8 3  8 22
4 4  9 4  9 26
5 5 10 5 10 30
>
```

Comment: looks like it :) but I need to refer to reference the first and last consecutive column names rather than the whole dataframe.  How would I do that?

Comment: Subset the argument going into `rowSums` accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's exactly what I'm asking how to do.  I'll keep looking and see if I can find an answer before you can get back to this page.

Comment: I'm wanting to say something like df[col(df$a):col(df$d)] but thats not right

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for a way to not explicitly write out `a + b + c + d + ...`?

If so, how about `rowSums()`

```
df$e <- with(df, rowSums(df))
```

Comment: Thanks... same comment as to Dirk, yes but I need to refer to reference the first and last consecutive column names rather than the whole dataframe. How would I do that?